# How to draw the Errera's graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tkz-graph

someone could you give me an example to draw this graph? My difficulty is set lengths in each vertex, I use [`tkz-graph`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-graph?lang=en)

## Uncompleted example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \SetGraphUnit{2}
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
        \SetVertexNoLabel
        \Vertex[x=0, y=0]{v1}
        \Vertex[x=10,y=0]{v2}
        \Vertex[x=5,y=0.5]{v3}
        \Edges(v1,v2,v3,v1)
        \Vertex[x=2.5,y=1]{v4}
        \Vertex[x=7.5,y=1]{v5}
        \Edges(v3,v4,v5,v3)
        \Vertex[x=4,y=1.5]{v6}
        \Vertex[x=8,y=1.5]{v7}
        %Continue ...
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think that there is another way to draw

[image: Errera graph]

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the `graphdrawing` library of TikZ in the manual?

Comment: @percusse I am not sure if the algorithms of the `graphdrawing` library are able to deal with an [Errera graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errera_graph), but I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks @percusse, I found a presentation and a nice article of Graph Drawing in TikZ by Till Tantau and a poster from Graph Drawing and Network Visualization :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily Mathematica has the graph data. Unfortunately, my French is practically nonexistent, so I cannot appreciate the benefits of that package.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \SetGraphUnit{2}
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
        \SetVertexNoLabel
        \foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in {4/ 13, 4/ 6, -0.2/ 5, 2/ 2.2, -6/ -1, 6/ 2.2, 
    9.5/ 1.6, 2.7/ 5, 4.8/ 7.8, 4/ 10.4, -1.5/ 1.6, 14/ -1, 4/ 3.6, 
    5.3/ 5, 3.2/ 7.8, 4/ 0.3, 8.1/ 5}
        {\Vertex[x=\X,y=\Y]{v\Z}}
        \Edges(v2,v8,v13,v14,v2)
        \Edges(v5,v12,v16,v5)
        \Edges(v5,v11,v16,v7,v12)
        \Edges(v11,v4,v16,v6,v7)
        \Edges(v4,v8,v15,v10,v9,v14,v6)
        \Edges(v4,v13,v6,v4)
        \Edges(v13,v2,v15,v9,v2)
        \Edges(v3,v10,v17)
        \Edges(v11,v15,v3)
        \Edges(v7,v9,v17)
        \Edges(v5,v3,v11)
        \Edges(v12,v17,v7)
        \Edges(v5,v1,v12)
        \Edges(v3,v1,v17)
        \Edges(v1,v10)
        \Edges(v11,v8)
        \Edges(v7,v14)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ingenious answer, @marmot please could you show how you got that data (if it's in Mathematica commands), I would also like to get your graphs from Solfer, Heawood.

I think Mathematica has something similar to http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_database.html

Comment: @Oromion [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ErreraGraph.html) is the link to the *Mathematica* notebook. I just typed `GraphData["ErreraGraph"] // InputForm` and used a regex c & p to convert the vertices to the list in `\foreach`, and the edges I drew by hand because I figured that understanding the *Mathematica* syntax for that may take longer.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much, it works :)
https://i.imgur.com/qbMWTCF.png